# Query Entitiy Framework cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to perform an explicit `Where` query on the Entity Framework cache? I know that I can use `Find` to look for an entity in the cache (based on the entities primary key).

Code sample:

```
var person = new PersonToStoreInDb() { Id = 1, Name = "John" };
dbSet.Add(person);
// Perform some other code
...
// DbContext.SaveChanges was NOT called!
var personFromDbSet = bSet.Where(p => p.Name == "John").First();
// personFromDbSet is null because it was not sent towards DB via SaveChanges
```

Comment: You probably want to utilize `bSet.Local`

Comment: `DbSet.Local` documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @[grek40](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40): Thanks for your comment `DbSet.Local` did the job. Please post your comment as answer!

Comment: @Moerwald sidenote: when you add a profile link on the user in "@user" mention, the user will not receive a notification.

Comment: @grek40, thx, got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework manages the cached data in `DbSet.Local`. It is an observable collection and Linq queries like `Where` can be applied to it. It will contain the loaded entries as well as entries of different state like `added` and `removed` until `SaveChanges` is called.